# which source file in rust language source refers_to/parse language keywords

Tags: rust, lexer

I want to change keyword spellings in Rust language.
For example, `for` -> `phur`, so where should I look in [rustc source code](https://gitlab.com/heksadesiml/heksip)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't just the one place you'd need to change.

The keywords themselves are defined in `src/librustc_span/symbol.rs` but many things in the compiler internals rely on those keyword not to change, including:

- macro expansion
- Any kind of syntactic sugar relying on the `quote!` family of macros.
- pretty printing
- the test suite